# Enable/Disable Solr Admin Features

Tags: solr, lucene, jetty, solrcloud, solr6

Is it a way to enable or disable solr features only for admin console or dashboard. For example, I want that someone can import data only by using curl command and not by accessing through the admin console. As there is a possibility that someone in the team would import data with parameter to clean collection as checked.

Comment: The admin interface uses the same API as what you're accessing through curl. The Admin interface is just a Javascript application on top of the regular API (it calls back to the same API endpoints as you'd use with `curl`). If it can be accessed through the Admin interface, it can be accessed through the regular API.

Comment: Ok thanks, so the only way is to make it password protected so no one can access admin. If yes, then in which file do I have to set the username and password so only one with the credentials can access the dashboard.

Comment: See https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/authentication-and-authorization-plugins.html

Comment: {
 "authentication":{
  "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
  "blockUnknown": true,
  "credentials":{
   "solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="
  }
 },
 "authorization":{
  "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
  "permissions":[{
   "collection":"collections1",
   "path":"/collections1/dataimport",
   "params": {
    "actions": ["clean"]
   }
  }],
  "user-role":{
   "solr":"admin"
  }
 }
}
added this in security.json to add password for clean parameter, but isn't working. could you please help a little.

Comment: I want that whenever someone adds clean param in its URL, solr should ask for username and parameter.